# "In need of moderator intervation" and "other" flag textboxes overflow the flagging dialog

Tags: bug, design, flag-dialog

The styling on the "Other" textbox in the flagging dialog is broken; the textbox overflows.

[image]

Tested in Chrome and Firefox, on SO and MSO.

Comment: Still not fixed ?